# What is the dynamic type of this object?

Tags: java

I am JAVA beginner. I am confused about this code

```java
Map<Integer, Map<String, Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

This is a map of map, and I know the outer map is a hashmap, but what is the type of the inner map?

Comment: The type of inner map is `Map<String, Integer>` which is also a `Map` in which the key is of `String` type and value is of `Integer` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is kind of like asking:

> What is the dynamic type of an element in this list?
>
> ```
> List<Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
> ```

There isn't even *one* element in the list! The same thing happens here. There are no inner maps in the outer map, so it does not make sense to ask what "the inner map's" type is.

Also note that there aren't just *two* types involved in this "nested map". `new HashMap<>()` means `new HashMap<Integer, Map<String, Integer>>()` It' not

> an outer map of type `HashMap`, capable of containing one certain implementation of `Map`

It's

> an outer map of type `HashMap`, capable of containing *any* implementations of `Map`

Using the aforementioned `list` example:

```
list.add((Integer)1);
list.add((Double)1.0);
```

It doesn't make sense to ask "what is *the* dynamic element type of the list?", because, well, *which one do you mean*? Each element's dynamic type is different.

With `Map`, one inner map could be `HashMap`, and another could be `TreeMap`. *Which one do you mean?*

Therefore, a better way to ask such a question is e.g. "what is the dynamic type of the inner map associated with the key `1`? (assuming such a map is put into the outer map beforehand)"

Answer (score 2):

The dynamic type of a **value** is its type at runtime; an expression or a variable does not have a well-defined "dynamic type" because an expression's value can have a different type at runtime each time the expression is evaluated; and a variable might hold values of different types at different times. Some expressions might never be evaluated at runtime, and some variables might never hold a value (e.g. a field belonging to a class which is never instantiated, or a local variable of a method which is never invoked), so in those cases there aren't even different dynamic types at different times.

In your question, you are asking about the dynamic type of something that doesn't necessarily exist at runtime, or which might take different values at different times, so the question doesn't really make sense. There may even be multiple inner maps at the same time, each with different types at runtime.

On the other hand, it does make sense to ask about the *static type* of the inner map(s), i.e. the type at compile-time. This is `Map<String, Integer>` because that's what it's declared to be.

Answer (score 1):

In java, `Map` is an interface. An interface is also considered a *type* just as a class is considered a *type*. In order to add an entry to variable `map`, you will need to supply an instance of some class that implements the `Map` interface. This can be a class that you write or an existing class that implements the `Map` interface, like `HashMap`, for example. Hence you cannot know what the actual type for the "value" part of the entry in `map` will be, just from the declaration of variable `map`.

Answer (score -2):

It is `null`. You have to instantiate the inner entry e.g.

```
map.put(1, new HashMap<>()); // know you know the type.
```

Comment: `null` is not a type.

Comment: @kaya3 that's not true. [It is a special type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1); it's just not the type here.

Comment: @AndyTurner There is a "special null type" but it is not named "null"; it has no name. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html

Comment: The null type is often called bottom, because it is at the bottom of the type hierarchy - it's sole value (`null`) is a member of every other type.

Comment: Java's special null type is not a bottom type; for example, `(int) null` is a type error: `incompatible types: <nulltype> cannot be converted to int`.